# Re-size page inside window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window with a tabcontrol inside of it, and each tabitem will parent a frame, which is bound to a page object. But I can't seem to be able to make the frame/page resize to fit the "main window". Here's the code I have:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Mplayer.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  Title="Mplayer" 
                  Initialized="Window_Initialized" Height="770" Width="1125">


<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1125" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <TabItem Header="Home" x:Name="HomeTab">
        <TabItem.Content>
            <Frame Source="HomePage.xaml" Margin="0,0,7,-697"/>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>


</controls:MetroWindow>
```

And here's the "HomePage.xaml"

```
<Page x:Class="Mplayer.HomePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  Height="770" Width="1125"
Title="HomePage" Foreground="Black">

<Grid Background="#373737">
    <Grid Background="#585858" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

I hope you understand my question, and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

**Remove harcoded height and width** from page definition as well as **TabControl** definiton:

```
Height="770" Width="1125"
```

Comment: Ah, that on it's own did not do the job, but apparently I had to make the tabcontrol itself bigger and fit the whole screen. That was the problem cause.. But thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also why have you set hardcoded `width` and `height` on TabControl as well? Remove that as well, let WPF window do its job for fitting it automatically. TabControl will take size of Window.

Answer (score 0):

You set the height and width for TabControl and HomePage explicitly. Remove those values both in Page and TabControl.

```
  <TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Home" x:Name="HomeTab">
        <Frame Source="HomePage.xaml"/>            
    </TabItem>
  </TabControl>
```